# data for my app in AppEngine (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to import some data to my app, i'm 'n00b', thats my 1st app, so any advice is welcome,

the data that i will upload is about 350mb, its a .csv, i tryed to upload with the bulk upload, but i got the error :

Unable to download kind stats for all-kinds downloa
Kind stats are generated periodically by the appser
Kind stats are not available on dev_appserver.

i searched a little, and i found that is because the app doesnt have de stats, i create the model and populate with some entitie, it was some days ago and the app doesnt have the statistics, i need a advice, what would be the best way to upload the amount of data to the app ?

if is useful, the data is here:

http://dados.gov.br/dataset/atendimentos-de-consumidores-nos-procons-sindec

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the autotmatic option generate `bulkloader.yaml` . For doing the auto generation, app engine uses the datastore statistics as the reference. Initially you had no data and hence no statistics and so you got the error related to no data stat.

Later when you added data to your datastore, your data statistics may still be empty because it normally takes upto 24 hours and even upto few days for app engine to update datastore statistics . So your data stats must still be empty and so auto generation option will not work.

You can follow the [bulk upload documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Editing_the_Configuration_File) and manually create a bulkloader.yaml based on the example given there and modify to match your datastore fields and their types. Using this manually generated file, you should be able to proceed.

Comment: Thanks Tony !

Do you know if this is viable for a .csv with about 350mb ? I do a simples test, upload as a .csv file to the app, and open the file to insert line by line, it took about one sec. for each 5 entities, in this tendency it would took more than 20 hours to insert each entitie, with bulk loader is faster ? in the dev env., is 10x faster.

Do you know any other alternative to serve data to the app ?

[]'s